# Dynamic tables with jQuery

Tags: jquery

How i can create a dynamic tables with jQuery?
EXAMPLE: jQuery dialog ask user how many rows in tables he want? User enter a number of rows and then jQuery create rows from that number. I think this can be done with jQuery, but how to do it?

Comment: http://tinyurl.com/mkop8he

Comment: @zod Alternatively, http://goo.gl/wnnaEw

Answer (score 1):

The simplest table making function might look something like this

```
function makeTable (cols, rows) {
    var html = "<table>", // Start your html
    tmpCols = 0;          // Temporary variable to use in loops
    while (rows--) { // Loop through rows

        html += "<tr>"; // Start new row
        tmpCols = cols; // Cache passed number of columns

        while (tmpCols--) { // Loop through cols
            html+= "<td></td>"; // Add new cells
        }

        html += "</tr>" // Close row
    }
    html += "</table>"; // Close table
    return html;        // Return html
}
```

Of course you might want to have more control over various aspects of the table (attributes or content, etc.). Update your question with more details about what you need and then we can help you better :)

Answer (score 0):

You've should of make some research before asking this.

A way to do this very easily would be to do something like this :

```
var nbRow = 10;

var content = '<table>';
for(var i=0; i<nbRow; i++){
    content += '<tr><td>Lorem ipsum</td></tr>';
}
content += '</table>';
$('body').append(content);
```

You replace the `nbRow` by the value you get from the user's choice.

[**Here's a fiddle to show you what it give**](http://jsfiddle.net/kGxbd/)